# Recolor bootstrap-datetimepicker

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap-3, less, bootstrap-datetimepicker

I am using [bootstrap-datetimepicker](http://eonasdan.github.io/bootstrap-datetimepicker/) and I wan't to recolor `.today` flag, but I can't find right `css` selector.

This is what I have:

```
#datetimepicker .dropdown-menu {
    td.active{
        color: red;
        background-color: blue;
    }

    td.today:not(.active) {
        color: white;
        background-color: orange;
    }
 }
```

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change

```
.bootstrap-datetimepicker-widget table td.active.today:before {
    border-bottom-color: #fff;
}
```

You would probably want to change `border-bottom-color: #337ab7;` also in

```
.bootstrap-datetimepicker-widget table td.today:before {
    content: '';
    display: inline-block;
    border: solid transparent;
    border-width: 0 0 7px 7px;
    border-bottom-color: #337ab7;
    border-top-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 4px;
    right: 4px;
}
```

Answer (score 5):

The class names may change time to time due to updates version of plugin.

```
.bootstrap-datetimepicker-widget.dropdown-menu {
  background-color: #30363b;
  border-color: #2b3135;
  width: 100%;
}
.bootstrap-datetimepicker-widget.dropdown-menu:after,
.bootstrap-datetimepicker-widget.dropdown-menu:before {
  display: none !important;
}
.bootstrap-datetimepicker-widget.dropdown-menu .arrow {
  display: none !important;
}
.bootstrap-datetimepicker-widget.dropdown-menu .arrow:after,
.bootstrap-datetimepicker-widget.dropdown-menu .arrow:before {
  display: none !important;
}
.bootstrap-datetimepicker-widget.dropdown-menu a span:hover,
.bootstrap-datetimepicker-widget.dropdown-menu a span:focus {
  background-color: #32aa62 !important;
  color: #fff !important;
}
```